# Definition of a geodesic ball?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, geometry

I think it goes along the lines of: a ball made of a series of flat sides. Also is a [geodesic ball](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=geodesic+ball) and [geodesic dome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_dome) the same thing?

Comment: This is "geodesic" in a completely different sense than what is meant by the term in the context of general relativity/differential geometry. It's definition has nothing to do with physics.